# Dropdown getting hidden behind slider. (z-index not working.)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Im having problems with getting the dropdown to show infront of the slider. Its not working to add z-index on the dropdown, but i can add z-index to the slider but then the navigation on the slider is not working.

DEMO: **http://multicopterphoto.no/983402342.php**

**Slider is from amazingslider.com**

**The drop down is on *FOTO***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the z-index on div.navigation.
So

```
.navigation {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
height: 90px;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e8ed;
z-index: 100000;
}
```

Will do it

Comment: Cool! :) This .navigation element is the top level element. Thats why the z-index has to be on this one. (Just so you know it for next time)

Comment: Okay, tnx for letting me know. I will remember it next time. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `z-index:-1` to this element `#amazingslider-1`

Comment: A minus value on z-index is a IE only thing

Comment: What do you mean is IE only thing @MortenOC ?

Comment: Back in the days, only IE could understand a negative z-index.